# Getting wrong result in Nagios when using check_apt

Tags: linux, debian, nagios

I have 1 Nagios "master?" and 3 slaves running. I get the correct data from the slaves on all checks except for the check_apt where all slaves get the master result.

The scenario today was that i added this to hostgroups.cfg

```
define hostgroup {
        hostgroup_name  system-packages
        alias           APT status on all servers
        members         *
}
```

And added this to services.cfg

```
define service {
        hostgroup_name                  system-packages
        service_description             APT
        check_command                   check_apt
        use                             generic-service
        notification_interval           0 ; set > 0 if you want to be renotified
}
```

Then when i restarted the Nagios3, the master reported that 3 packages needed to be updated, then after a while the other reports came in, also with 3 packages.

That i thought was ok, they got installed on the same day, so shouldn't differ.

But then i updated those 3 packages on the master and the warnings on the slaves also disappeared, so somehow the slaves gets the result from the master.

When i run the check_apt command on a single slave, it reports the correct data:

```
user@remote-system:~$ /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_apt
APT CRITICAL: 3 packages available for upgrade (3 critical updates).
```

I don't get any error in the logs or anything. Are really out of ideas what can be the problem, so any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Nagios questions should probably be on Serverfault, not here.

Comment: Damn, first post and i manage to screw up :|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`check_apt` can only show results from the host it's running on (e.g., localhost).

To run check_apt against other hosts, you need an agent of some sort. Like [NRPE](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Monitoring-Agents/NRPE--2D-Nagios-Remote-Plugin-Executor/details) or [check_by_ssh](https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_by_ssh.html) (with keys).

This applies to any plugin that is checking an "internal" thing like APT, load, memory, disk usage, SMART health, etc.

Edit: To clarify, your service def that applies this check to the `system-packages` needs to be more like this, because right now you're running `check_apt` on localhost for every check:

```
define service {
    hostgroup_name                  system-packages
    service_description             APT
    check_command                   check_nrpe!check_apt
    use                             generic-service
}
```

Or perhaps `check_nrpe_1arg` instead, if using the Debian/Ubuntu packaged NRPE.

Comment: Yes i am using NRPE on the slaves, they report load/disk usage/memory just fine.

Comment: If your check_command doesn't start with "check_nrpe", then they probably don't ;-)

Comment: You are so correct, noticed now that the disk info was same on all results, and the load differed just because they result came from different times :D And for future reference, just check_nrpe! was needed, not the check_nrpe_1arg even thou im using the debian package. Big Thanks